# Simple Tablike functionality with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a click event on three links that shows a related section, but I want to close the current open section when clicking another link and show the new related section with a slideToggle() animation. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
    // HTML
    <ul>
        <li><a id="privacy" href="#privacy-section">Privacy</a></li> 
        <li><a id="cookies" href="#cookies-section">Cookies</a></li> 
        <li><a id="imprint" href="#imprint-section">Imprint</a></li> 
    </ul>

    <section id="privacy-section" class="privacy">
        Content…
    </section>
    <section id="cookies-section" class="cookies">
        Content…
    </section>
    <section id="imprint-section" class="imprint">
        Content…
    </section>

    // JS
    $('#imprint, #privacy, #cookies').on('click', function(event) {
        var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
        target.slideToggle();

    if( target.length ) {
        event.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is 'accordion'

Comment: you are looking for accordion,check the fiddle-http://jsfiddle.net/FKAAM/4/

Comment: Yeah thanks - that´s more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Footer Accordion

$('#imprint, #privacy, #cookies').on('click', function(event) {
var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));

if(target.hasClass('is-closed')) {
    $('.is-open').addClass('is-closed').removeClass('is-open');
    target.removeClass('is-closed');
    target.addClass('is-open');
}
else {
    target.removeClass('is-open');
    target.addClass('is-closed');
}

if( target.length ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
}
});
```